# Fetching Columns of a multiple rows in one row

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

I have a DB table with records as shown below,

```
ID   ATTR_NAME   ATTR_VALUE 
1    ABC          DEF
1    GHI          JKL
1    MNO          PQR
```

I would like to get a single row as

```
ID  ABC GHI  MNO
1   DEF JKL  PQR
```

Comment: And PL/SQL is not an option?

Comment: PL SQL is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a little fragile and not that future proofed, but Pivot can give you what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT attr_name, attr_value
   FROM   test
)
PIVOT
(  MIN(attr_value)
   FOR attr_name IN ( 'ABC','GHI','MNO' )
)
```

However, I'd advise that you consider if you really need it in that format and see if you can get it out in a more natural format.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, 
   sum(case when attr_name = 'ABC' then attr_value end) as ABC, 
   sum(case when attr_name = 'GHI' then attr_value end) as GHI, 
   sum(case when attr_name = 'MNO' then attr_value end) as MNO
from DB
group by ID;
```