# T-SQL How to "Flatten" top 3 rows into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've searched for an answer to this question and found questions similar to my own, however I do not have a "ColumnHeader" column to denote which field the record should go into.  Ex:

[TSQL Pivot without aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function)

[trying to flatten rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651511/trying-to-flatten-rows-into-columns)

[Fetching Columns of a multiple rows in one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568983/fetching-columns-of-a-multiple-rows-in-one-row)

My problem is thus - I have data in this format (selected as a top 3 result from a product recommendation query):

```
 ------------------------------
 CustID | StyleNo | Brand | ID 
 ------------------------------
    1   |   ABC   | BrandA| 1 
 ------------------------------
    1   |   DEF   | BrandB| 2 
 ------------------------------
    1   |   GHI   | BrandC| 3 
 ------------------------------
    2   |   JKL   | BrandA| 4 
 ------------------------------
    2   |   MNO   | BrandB| 5 
 ------------------------------
    2   |   PQR   | BrandD| 6 
 ------------------------------
```

That I'd like to make look like this:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
 CustID | StyleNo1| StyleNo2| StyleNo3 | Brand1 | Brand2 | Brand3
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
    1   |   ABC   |   DEF   |   GHI    | BrandA | BrandB | BrandC 
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
    2   |   JKL   |   MNO   |   PQR    | BrandA | BrandB | BrandD
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

In order for my program to simply read the row of recommendations for each customer.

What I have attempted is a `PIVOT` - however I have nothing to really aggregate upon. I've also attempted the `Min(Case...When...Then...End)` as outlined in the second linked question, but as stated I don't have reference to a "Header" column.

The ID column is completely inconsequential for the time being, but it may help to solve this problem. It is NOT needed in the end result.

I am currently using SQLServer 2012

Comment: try stuff https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

Comment: @happymacarts STUFF seems to enable me to parse the data into a comma separated list of values, which I'd have to decode on the front-end. Is there a simpler way of just providing tabular data in the format I've described? Please let me know if I don't quite understand your solution.

Comment: maybe try a group by or look at grouping sets i think i misunderstood your oP

Comment: is the target table structure fixed? you always have 3 records to flat, or up to 3, or it could be any number.

Comment: The target table has up to 3 recommendations, my select statement will check to see if the 2nd or 3rd recommendation is NULL before using the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the window function Row_Number() and a conditional aggregation

```
 Select CustID
       ,StyleNo1 = max(case when RN=1 then StyleNo else null end)
       ,StyleNo2 = max(case when RN=2 then StyleNo else null end)
       ,StyleNo3 = max(case when RN=3 then StyleNo else null end)
       ,Brand1   = max(case when RN=1 then Brand   else null end)
       ,Brand2   = max(case when RN=2 then Brand   else null end)
       ,Brand3   = max(case when RN=3 then Brand   else null end)
 From  (
         Select *,RN = Row_Number() over (Partition By CustID Order by StyleNo,Brand)
         From  YourTable
       ) A
 Where RN<=3
 Group By CustID
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: @TramelJones Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is called "pivoting" - for this you could use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx). A better way IMHO is to use approach that Jeff Moden talks about in [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/).

```
WITH idSort AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY ID) FROM @yourTable
)
SELECT
  CustID,
  StyleNo1 = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN StyleNo END),
  StyleNo2 = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN StyleNo END),
  StyleNo3 = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN StyleNo END),
  Brand1   = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN Brand   END),
  Brand2   = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN Brand   END),
  Brand3   = MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN Brand   END)
FROM idSort
GROUP BY CustID;
```

Comment: Thanks for the article! Good tip

Answer (score 0):

Other approach can be using CTE's and Cross Apply.

```
CREATE TABLE #UnFlattenedData
    (
      CustID TINYINT ,
      StyleNo CHAR(3) ,
      Brand CHAR(6) ,
      ID TINYINT
    );

INSERT  INTO #UnFlattenedData
        ( CustID, StyleNo, Brand, ID )
VALUES  ( 1, -- CustID - tinyint
          'ABC', -- StyleNo - char(3)
          'BrandA', -- Brand - char(6)
          1  -- ID - tinyint
          ),
        ( 1, -- CustID - tinyint
          'DEF', -- StyleNo - char(3)
          'BrandB', -- Brand - char(6)
          2  -- ID - tinyint
          ),
        ( 1, -- CustID - tinyint
          'GHI', -- StyleNo - char(3)
          'BrandC', -- Brand - char(6)
          3  -- ID - tinyint
          ),
        ( 2, -- CustID - tinyint
          'JKL', -- StyleNo - char(3)
          'BrandA', -- Brand - char(6)
          4  -- ID - tinyint
          ),
        ( 2, -- CustID - tinyint
          'MNO', -- StyleNo - char(3)
          'BrandB', -- Brand - char(6)
          5  -- ID - tinyint
          ),
        ( 2, -- CustID - tinyint
          'PQR', -- StyleNo - char(3)
          'BrandD', -- Brand - char(6)
          6  -- ID - tinyint
          );
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   * ,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY u1.CustID ORDER BY u1.ID ) AS R1
               FROM     #UnFlattenedData AS u1
             ),
        u1
          AS ( SELECT   C1.CustID ,
                        U1.StyleNo ,
                        U1.Brand
               FROM     cte AS C1
                        INNER JOIN #UnFlattenedData AS U1 ON U1.CustID = C1.CustID
                                                             AND U1.ID = C1.ID
               WHERE    C1.R1 = 1
             ),
        u2
          AS ( SELECT   C1.CustID ,
                        U1.StyleNo ,
                        U1.Brand
               FROM     cte AS C1
                        INNER JOIN #UnFlattenedData AS U1 ON U1.CustID = C1.CustID
                                                             AND U1.ID = C1.ID
               WHERE    C1.R1 = 2
             ),
        u3
          AS ( SELECT   C1.CustID ,
                        U1.StyleNo ,
                        U1.Brand
               FROM     cte AS C1
                        INNER JOIN #UnFlattenedData AS U1 ON U1.CustID = C1.CustID
                                                             AND U1.ID = C1.ID
               WHERE    C1.R1 = 3
             )
    SELECT  u1.CustID ,
            u1.StyleNo AS StyleNo1 ,
            u2.StyleNo AS StyleNo2 ,
            u3.StyleNo AS StyleNo3 ,
            u1.Brand AS Brand1 ,
            u2.Brand AS Brand2 ,
            u3.Brand AS Brand3
    FROM    u1
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    *
                          FROM      u2
                          WHERE     u2.CustID = u1.CustID
                        ) AS u2
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    *
                          FROM      u3
                          WHERE     u3.CustID = u1.CustID
                        ) AS u3;
```

[image: ResultSet]

Comment: Does using a CTE with `CROSS APPLY` have any performance benefit over the cross tab? (accepted answer)